# Explicitly Unwrapped Optionals in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

In Swift, if I have a property of a class that is another class, I declare it as an implicitly unwrapped optional:

```swift
class MyClass {
  var prop: OtherClass!

  init(prop: OtherClass) {
    self.prop = prop
  }

  explodeProp() {
    // don't need to unwrap it, because it's implicitly unwrapped
    // which is safe because it's always assigned in the initializer
    prop.explode() 
  }
}
```

In Typescript, I think I have to do it this way:

```js
export class MarkdownNode {
  tag = "";
  text = "";
  document: FoldingDocument | null = null; // will never actually be null
  parent: MarkdownNode | null = null; // could indeed be null

  constructor(tag: string, text: string, document: FoldingDocument) {
    this.tag = tag;
    this.text = text;
    this.document = document;
  }

  addSibling(node: MarkdownNode) {
    if (!this.parent) {
      this.document!.nodes.push(node) // no choice but to force-unwrap?
    } else {
      this.parent.children.push(node
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a way to do implicitly unwrapped optionals in TypeScript? Is it maybe on the way?

Comment: "will never actually be null" --- why do you initialise it with `null` and type as `| null` then?

Comment: Oh right, TS won't complain if I define it in the initializer. That was dumb. Sorry about that.

Comment: The same question about Swift: why you declare your property as optional, if there is no way to create object without settings this property? Your example should not set this property in constructor to be illustrative. But then you cannot be sure it will never be `nil`, it is just the lifecycle of this class objects that requires settings `prop` after creating to perform properly (it is usually due to cyclic dependencies between objects, like in uikit), otherwise it is considered bug and application MUST crash (that is why you don't use explicitly unwrapped optionals and optional chaining)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In TS (guess same in swift) you could define value in constructor as well. Therefore if you dont expect value to be `null` - you should not add it to the type.

Here is [playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/en/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD2IAmBLAdgcwCL2AVwFsBTNAF2gG8AoaW6NeJIiALmgFkwAnAayXgDuaAHKMiAbQC60ALzQpAbioBfKlVCQYnXvyGimlGtFJgMbCKS7oMS2qSIAPUucvXb0fvmJk2CZNZwvElJ3AAduYLZtPkERMWgAH3o8EBBZZNSFaAB6bOhgeBSkaHQmImKAIyIMkCNgAAsUZC4SKO4YvTEpdMU1WgK0Cy48YFJ4LgAKEzNoIesAGmNHZ1nXTEXPQki4RFRMQK2yAEpDOmNGiAA6afTp9zsL6+Xb5fvzlCvN73I5L+D3VRGMBIJAAZRQFRA1gmDCYbR0sX0RBO1DOKAAZtAJgBCUiPcItY6nM7vT64Q6kS6w5iXUJ4CD1GFiE65ejwfL1eAoYDVCp4chjaDo8Y8gC0eDQAi4YFCAH4jLRlNAiCAINVUSS8R9aREyJcGk0kITafTGdSjgroKpFSogA)

```
class FoldingDocument {
    nodes: MarkdownNode[] = [];
}

class MarkdownNode {
  tag: string;
  text: string;
  document: FoldingDocument;
  parent: MarkdownNode | null = null; // could indeed be null
  children: MarkdownNode[] = [];

  constructor(tag: string, text: string, document: FoldingDocument) {
    this.tag = tag;
    this.text = text;
    this.document = document;
  }

  addSibling(node: MarkdownNode) {
    if (!this.parent) {
      this.document.nodes.push(node) // no choice but to force-unwrap?
    } else {
      this.parent.children.push(node)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How does it relate to OP's question, he asked about implicitly unwrapped optionals, not usual ones?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, Typescript has this functionality, it is called [Definite Assignment Assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#definite-assignment-assertions) and looks like this (note exclamation mark):

```js
let x! string; // variable declaration
class Foo {
  bar!: number; // property declaration
}
```

Note, however, that in typescript definitely assigned variables/properties has type `T`, not `Optional<T>`, as in Swift, and just become `undefined` when unassigned, so they are just the way to violate typecheck rules and doesn't affect runtime behaviour. You will not get errors like `got nil while implicitly unwrapping optional value`, but you just will get `undefined` and only when you try to use it (like trying to call method), you get error, compare:
Swift

```swift
class Foo {
  var bar: String!
}
let x = Foo()
let y: String = x.bar // boom! Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value
```

Typescript:

```js
class Foo {
  bar!: string;
}
let x = new Foo()
let y: string = x.bar // it is ok, we just assigned `undefined` to string variable
someObject.name = y;
// years later in a galaxy far far away
let nameLength = someObject.name.length; // boom! Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

So, be careful, definite assignement is big footgun